# why I'm getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value' when printing values without loop

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I've worked on data structures in C++, now I've switched to python and facing an issue here.

When I try to access values of node without loop it always through an error
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

```
def solution(l):
    head=ListNode(None)
    head.next=l
    current=head.next #also tried head.next.next gets error on this one too
    print(current.value)
    return True
```

[error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlBQd.png)

But when I try to print values in loop all the values are printed and I don't understand the science behind it

```
def solution(l):
    head=ListNode(None)
    head.next=l
    current=head
    while(current):
        print(current.value)
        current=current.next
    return True
```

and here is the output of it
[printed output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNHft.png)

Given that rest of the syntax is correct

Defined Node format is as follow:

```
#   def __init__(self, x):
#     self.value = x
#     self.next = None
```

Now my question is why it prints values in loop and not in single line statment

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `l` is an instance of `ListNode` here.

You must always verify that a variable is not `None` before accessing one of its attributes (such as `next`).

The second solution does this every time a an assignment is made to `current`. It will exit the loop as soon as `current` is `None`.

The first solution will often work, except when an empty list is passed as argument, i.e. when `l` is `None`. Then it will trigger the error you mentioned. In that case also `current` will be `None`, and then accessing `current.next` is invalid.